# OBJ model barely rendering in Blender 2.78

Tags: rendering, objects, makehuman

I just made the [following model](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/blender-repo/tom_slick.obj) in [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/):

[image]

I export him as an OBJ file (which produces both an OBJ and an MTL file on my file system), then I open Blender and import the OBJ. I see:

[image]

When I click `SHIFT+Z` to render him (and apply textures, etc.), I see:

[image]

If you look close, you can kinda/sorta make out his eyes and a few other white blurbs. **What's going on here?!?** Is this a bug in MakeHuman, Blender, or me just not using the UI correctly? Why is this rendering so weird?!

Comment: AMD GPU involved in the process?

Comment: Thanks @cegaton (+1) - nope, Intel (Macbook Pro). Any ideas?

Comment: Try rendering in cpu

Comment: Thanks, will do - but how do I do that?!

Comment: Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Are you using cycles or internal?